# What does response 101 mean in the context of socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm having an issue in my app where I should be getting response code 200 (and I do for the most part), but at certain points I'm getting response code 101. What exactly does this mean in the context of socket.io? I read that it means there is a switching of protocol, which is probably not something I want to be happening. It's a big problem because right after the log says 'DISCONNECTED USER', I get this response code returned and it screws up my application. Maybe it's just poor user connection? I'm thinking maybe it's because the transport policy goes from 'polling' to 'web sockets'? If this is the issue, how can I correct it?

I'm attaching images, but to be honest I don't even know what to put in terms of code so here's my socket.io initialization:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

function onConnection(socket){
  console.log("Connected a socket");
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("DISCONNECTED USER: " + socket.id);
  }
}
```

Client is in Swift and looks like:

```
var socket: SocketIOClient?

func establishConnection(_ completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        let socketUrlString: String = "serverURL"
        self.manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: socketUrlString)!, config: [.log(false), .reconnects(true), .extraHeaders(["header": "customheader"])])
        self.socket = manager?.defaultSocket
        self.socket?.connect()
        appState.socketIsConnected = true
        self.socket?.once(clientEvent: .connect, callback: { (data, emitter) in
            print("\n\n\n connection done!! \n\n\n")
            if completion != nil{
                completion!()
            }
        })
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDt48.png

Comment: [switching protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/101) - which is exactly what you DO want when using websockets

Comment: @Bravo but I'm not triggering any disconnect events--and everything works smoothly when all I see in the logs are response code 200s...which led me to believe that the 101 was the source of error. What else could it be?

Comment: no idea - the code you've shown doesn't even show how that function is called - also the client code may be wrong

Comment: @Bravo Thanks for telling me what I was missing--I added the client code. The only thing I can think of is if I'm calling the establish connection multiple times--would that cause this error?) It's pretty boilerplate though so I'm not sure how helpful it will be unless there are options I should have added...